# Simple Java Application in Docker - Could not find or load Main class

Tags: java, docker

I have created a simple Eclipse project having Main class inside src/com/docker/Main.java.
When i try to run it inside a docker container after building the image, i get the Could not find or load main class error.

Docker image content:

```
FROM openjdk:8
COPY . /app/
WORKDIR /app
RUN javac src/com/docker/Main.java

CMD ["java", "com.docker.Main"]
```

I tried several variations of RUN and CMD but nothing worked. I tried with slashes '/' but still did not worked.

```
CMD ["java", "com.docker.Main.java"]
CMD ["java", "com.docker.Main.class"]
```

If i run the following command after the `javac` part, it lists `Main.java` and `Main.class` files.

```
RUN ls src/com/docker/
```

Comment: Try with your workdir being /app/src .

Comment: you have to add `-cp src` to your `java` command

Comment: @Oo.oO i tried only -cp, did not work

Comment: Your code (generated class) is inside `src/com/docker/Main.class`. This is why you have to call `java -cp src com.docker.Main`

Comment: @Arnaud it worked. Why was that necessary ?

Comment: @Oo.oO it worked this way too. Thank you

Comment: @Nathan : You either have to be in the directory containing the base package (the src directory containing the base com package), or have this directory be in the classpath like suggested in the other comments. That way java will be able to find the class .

Comment: @Arnaud Oh, i see.
One more question. On inside my terminal, if i type `java src/com/docker/Main.java` it works, on the other hand if i only do `CMD ["java","src/com/docker/Main.java"]` inside the docker image, it doesn't work. What are the differences here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, maybe this picture will explain the parameters little bit more.

[image]